# Do i keep foreign passports after i confiscate them?

Tags: papers-please

I want to escape with my family to Obristan, but I need Obristan passports for forgeries. I've read other answers, and they say the same, confiscate Obristan passports. Should I confiscate only two passports? I have the passport jorji gave, I adopted my niece and my wife is still alive.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two family members left, you will need to steal two more passports. You also need one for yourself, which Jorji will give you.